# Redirect search page to search result page using nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, redirect

I want to redirect my page from

https://www.example.com/search?q=testtest  or
https://www.example.com/search/?q=testtest

To

https://www.example.com/search-results/?q=testtest

So I have added below the code in nginx. But redirect not working.

```
location = /search {
    if ($args  ~ "q=([^/]*)/?$"){
        rewrite ^/search-results/$ /?q=%1 redirect;
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not need to give `rewrite` the parameter, if it hasn't' changed. Also, you have the new URI in the wrong place. Try: `rewrite ^ /search-results/ redirect;`

Comment: @RichardSmith, Thanks for your reply. What about query string?

Comment: The `rewrite` directive will append the original query string intact. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: @RichardSmith, Its redirecting to home page with query string.

Comment: I want to redirect search-result page

Comment: You need to be more specific - what do you expect to type into the browser's address bar? What URL are you taken to to process the request? What configuration do you have to process the search request?